# How to remove this fpermissive error in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling, compiler-errors

passing ‘const IntBag’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

This is my code:
'''C++
**

```
> int IntBag::operator[](int index){     //get array item
>         return array_[index];
>     }
>     
>     IntBag::IntBag (const IntBag& a){        //copy constructr
>       size=a.getSize();
>       for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
>         int val=a[i];
>         array_[i]=val;
>       }
>     }
>     
>     int IntBag::getSize()const{    //get the size of the array
>       return size;
>     }
>     
>     IntBag& IntBag::operator = (const IntBag& a){
>       for(int i= 0; i< a.getSize(); i++) {
>         array_[i]=a[i];
>       }
>     }
```

**

---

> My error is:
> $ g++ intbag.cpp
> intbag.cpp: In copy constructor ‘IntBag::IntBag(const IntBag&)’:
> intbag.cpp:19:16: error: passing ‘const IntBag’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> 19 |     int val=a[i];
> |                ^
> intbag.cpp:12:5: note:   in call to ‘int IntBag::operator’
> 12 | int IntBag::operator[](int index){     //get array item
> |     ^~~~~~
> intbag.cpp: In member function ‘IntBag& IntBag::operator=(const IntBag&)’:
> intbag.cpp:30:18: error: passing ‘const IntBag’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> 30 |     array_[i]=a[i];
> |                  ^
> intbag.cpp:12:5: note:   in call to ‘int IntBag::operator’
> 12 | int IntBag::operator[](int index){     //get array item
> |     ^~~~~~
> intbag.cpp:32:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
> 31 |   }
> +++ |+  return *this;
> 32 | }
> | ^

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQFhC.jpg)

Comment: Don't post images of text. Copy the text instead.

Comment: Do not use the C tag for C++ questions.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove this fpermissive error in c++?

Don't call non-const qualified member functions on const values. In this case the non-const qualified member function is the subscript operator overload and the const value is the argument `const IntBag& a` of the assignment operator overload.

Given that the subscript operator overload doesn't modify the state of the object, nor return a non-const reference, there is no need for it not to be const qualified. As such, a simple solution is to declare the subscript operator const.

Comment: So I declared the operator as const. Now I am getting another error message: "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): in function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.7-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.7-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x82): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"